# A World Surrounded by a Powerful Energy Layer

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, creature-design

In my story the world is surrounded by a powerful energy layer. The life in that world is dependent on that energy, just like we are dependent on oxygen.

Is such a world possible? The energy would be the source of all living things on that planet, just as oxygen, water and food are for us. Or sunlight for plants.

How can both animal & plant life be dependent on that energy layer? Can that energy layer to be the destructive too? Magic or any supernatural thing is allowed but not a must.

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: What kind of energy are we talking about?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Nithya*! I am having a few problems understanding your question. Could you please [edit] your question and explain what kind of "destructor" you mean? It feels like you want something good to also be bad under certain circumstances, but it also feels like "destructor" is supposed to be some sort of villain. And what do you mean with "the life in that planet and the planet itself like"? Do you mean what the planet and life on such a planet would look like? That would be pretty broad.If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more.Have fun

Comment: For the moment I am voting to temporarily put this question on hold as "unclear what you are asking" until it's clarified what you are actually asking so that answers do answer your real question and to make sure that the question aligns with our communities guidelines.

Comment: @Raditz_35 actually, that is not completely correct. "Just energy" can exist e.g. in to form of electromagnetic fields. It just doesn't do anything until it is transferred to an object. Depending on how much realism you want to get, a layer of energy in form of photons or (e.g. electromagnetic) fields could surround the planet. Since "Magic or any supernatural thing is allowed", this could just be a field of magic energy.

Comment: What do you mean by energy layer? That is a pretty unspecific term. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Till I deleted my comment because I honestly don't care enough, have him have his pure energy, but I have to disagree with what you are writing since you bothered to comment. An electromagnetic field is an electromagnetic field and not "pure energy". Energy remains a property, perhaps of an electromagnetic field or a photon or whatever you wish. Pure energy remains a nonsensical idea. I don't disagree that the wikipedia definition doesn't have weaknesses, but it's a good starting point. One could interpret that he means whatever, but if you have to start guessing, the OP did a poor job

Comment: Nithya, while the pre-edit answers are creative, the answer to your question is no.  Our science today knows of no way to replace sunlight, oxygen, food, or anything else with an energy field for even a single creature, much less an entire biome.  This doesn't make your idea or story bad, run with it!  You simply don't have today's science to back you up, which is true for about 90% of all science fiction.  Regrettably, this makes your qustion primarily opinion-based (you can't tell us how to judge a good answer), so I can't vote to reopen.  (\*continued\*)

Comment: If you want to continue to pursue this question, I would recommend abandoning it and starting over fresh with our [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions).  That will help you iron out exactly what you're asking for and how to ask for it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Sunlight fits your description.

It can be fairly powerful, it pretty much surrounds the planet, is the source of all living things on this planet, plants and (some) animals directly depend on it, to a lesser degree humans directly depend on it as well (We need it to synthesize vitamin D in our skin).

It can also be a destroyer (if that is what you meant) - UV rays cause damage to DNA, rips molecules apart and bleaches things left out in the sun. Sunlight can cause sunburn and can be quite dangerous in hot and dry places like deserts.

The inhabitants could have evolved to require a large amount of sunlight (just like humans need vitamin d, but more) under a sun that puts out more light in the UV spectrum or simply more intense light, while beings not from this planet could have a hard time surviving with that level of UV radiation and/or heat.

A few thoughts:

- Your animals could have evolved to use photosynthesis - it's rare on earth, but exists so why couldn't this happen in a different world? You could for example "starve" to death after not being able to do photsynthesis for 7 days.
- If the sun was more intense, most people would expect more deserts, but while this might be the case, it would also cause more evaporation from the oceans, more clouds and a lot more rain (e.g. rain forest)

Comment: I would upvote your answer but sadly you have exactly 666 reputation

Comment: I upvoted before I noticed that.  Gracefully surrender the things of youth, Syzygy.

Comment: Really good answer except... large animals don't photosynthesize due to photosynthesis needing a large surface area, the larger the animal the lower the surface area. apart from my OCD needing to correct that point, good answer

Comment: @bladewraith large animals could be torus-shaped to increase surface area and allow photosynthesis closer to deep tissues. Or spindly, like trees, with leaf-like structures to increase surface areas. Or exceptionally low metabolisms.

Comment: @BladeWraith The sun would be more intense. And there are plenty of ways to increase surface area. They could have slower metabolisms, or there would be an upper limit in animal size due to their energy needs vs energy consumption. Larger animals could have adopted new and weird energy creation strategies to augmented their needs... like eating... and digestion.

Answer (score 2):

### Inductive charging.

Your "planet" is technically a moon orbiting a gas-giant, with another, larger, moon orbiting further away.  This results in large [Tidal Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force), much like the [Tidal Heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_heating) of the Jovian moon [Io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_(moon)).

Due to an unusual property of the seams of metallic ore threaded through your planet, this causes a strong fluctuating electromagnetic field close to the planet's surface.  Flora and fauna on the planet have evolved to draw electrical power from this field via [Inductive Charging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_charging).  This means that while they need to eat or use roots to acquire *materials* for growth and healing, they have a lesser (but not necessarily **no**) need for *energy* from their food.

Any animals that get too far away from the surface of the planet (e.g. by flying, or swimming at the surface of the oceans) will then need some way to store energy while they cannot draw it from the planet.

Depending on how strong the field is, you may find that modern electronics will not function - vacuum tubes, etc, would be the "high tech" route for intelligent life on the planet.  Also, for obvious reasons, the shifting magnetic field largely precludes being able to use a compass.

The field will get stronger as the tidal forces "charge" the planet, and slowly weaken (slightly?) until the next charge cycle.  The 'free energy' would likely also mean that lots of food on the planet contained *far* less sugar than on Earth!